# Hidden bootstrap section that appear with animation

Tags: javascript, jquery, slide

Is there any way I can make with a jQuery plugin or some javascript a hidden responsive bootstrap section that appear with an animation, like this one:

http://kjarninn.is/ (click BLAÐAHILLA in the navbar)

Comment: Like this what, exactly?

Comment: push the BLAÐAHILLA from navbar

Comment: Oh, you mean click that menu item. It's just a sliding div. No plugin needed. Take a look at `slideDown()`, `slideUp()`, and `slideToggle()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(function() {
    $('#slidePanel').hide();

    $('#panelShow').click(function() {
        $('#slidePanel').slideDown();
    });

    $('#panelHide').click(function() {
        $('#slidePanel').slideUp();
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/pRNe8/

Notice that jQuery is loaded in this fiddle, and that I've used some absolute positioning to prevent the panel from pushing the page content down.